# organizing matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

What is the best way of organizing/storing matrix in R ? Let's say I have 4 matrix and I would like to store them together.

```
a <- matrix(1:4,2,2)
b <- matrix(5:8,2,2)

d <- matrix(9:10,2,1)
e <- matrix(10:11,2,1)
```

I want to store the matrix like

```
a d
b e
```

i.e.

```
     [,1] [,2]       [,1]
[1,]    1    3  [1,]    9  
[2,]    2    4  [2,]   10 


     [,1] [,2]       [,1]
[1,]    5    7  [1,]   10  
[2,]    6    8  [2,]   11
```

Comment: Answers to this query will probably be a little subjective. What is the "best" way will depend on what you intend to do with the data. Do you need to access certain parts in a certain way? Are you going to need to merge additional data in later? What is the type of additional data you want to store alongside the matrix? Etc... etc..

Comment: Why do you want to to "store them together"? What's the argument against keeping them separate? Do they actually get used together in calculations?

Answer (score 4):

If they're all the same size you might consider an `array` (basically just a matrix with multiple dimensions).

If they're not but partition nicely, then @crmhaske's matrix solution is nice.  An additional option you might consider is defining a new S3 class and storing the partitioning information as attributes.

```
m <- structure(
  cbind(rbind(a,b),rbind(d,e)),
  locations = list( c(1:2,1:2), c(3:4,1:2), c(1:2,3), c(3:4,3) ),
  class = "myPartitionedMatrix"
)
```

Or just store them all as a list:

```
l <- list( a,b,c,d )
```

Answer (score 2):

```
cbind(rbind(a,b),rbind(d,e))

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    9
[2,]    2    4   10
[3,]    5    7   10
[4,]    6    8   11
```